# Reflecting The Fields of a Empty's Slices Underyling Type?

Tags: reflection, go

I have the following query builder function:

```
func CreateQuery(t interface{}, where string) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    b.WriteString("SELECT ")

    s := reflect.ValueOf(t).Elem()
    typeOfT := s.Type()

    for i := 0; i < s.NumField() - 1; i++ {
        b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s, ", typeOfT.Field(i).Name))
    }

    //Last one has no Comma
    b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s ", typeOfT.Field(s.NumField() - 1).Name))

    b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("FROM %s ", typeOfT.Name()))
    b.WriteString(where)
    fmt.Println(b.String())
}
```

There works fine when called as follows:

```
var dst FooStruct
CreateQuery(&dst, "")
```

But the following raises a "call of reflect.Value.NumField on slice Value" Panic:

```
var dst []FooStruct
CreateQuery(&dst, "")
```

How I can I make the function print the fields of a slice's underlying struct type? It seems like I want the inverse of reflect's `SliceOf` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call `NumField` or `Field` methods on a `reflect.Type` representing a struct (i.e. `t.Kind() == reflect.Struct`).

If you have a slice type, you can access the contained type via the `Elem` method, which returns another `reflect.Type`.  If the slice contains a struct, then you can call `NumField`/`Field` on this type.

Comment: Got it, so I need to do something like: `typeOfT := s.Type()`
and then `ContainedtypeOfT := typeOfT.Elem()`. Then the rest of the function references `ContainedtypeOfT` instead of `s` or `TypeofT`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the slice, calling `CreateQuery` for every query:

```
func CreateQueries(t interface{}, where string) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(t)

    if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        v = v.Elem()
    }

    if v.Kind() == reflect.Array || v.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
            CreateQuery(v.Index(i).Interface(), where)
        }
    }
}
```

Using [`reflect.Value.Index`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Index) you can access each field separately, calling `.Interface()` on the
value yields the `interface{}` type representation of that value, making it suitable to put
it in your `CreateQuery` function (which expects a `interface{}` value).